# Why immutable objects have a simple memory management in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, immutability

In Paul Hegarty's course, he recommends using immutable objects for memory management reasons. However, I couldn't find the reason for this.

So, why is an immutable object preferable for memory management reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary reason is that the `copy` operation for immutable objects is actually an alias for `retain` (or, with garbage collection, a no-op). This is valid because with correct usage of immutable objects, you can’t observe the difference between the original and the copy, except by pointer comparison.

This is important because “value objects”, such as strings, are often copied, to avoid precisely the situation Kenny Wyland describes. If you have a property declared `@property (copy) NSString *foo`, assigning an immutable string to it will retain it without significant overhead, while assigning a mutable string to it will copy it to avoid it changing behind the asignee’s back.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, it's not technically better for memory management purposes ***IF*** you know how to manage memory properly. My guess is that he's suggesting it for new cocoa developers because it will inherently help them avoid some pitfalls dealing with memory.

For example, if you have class A which has a member NSString *myString... then if you create an NSMutableString *mutable and set A.myString = mutable.... the writer of class A will expect myString not to change, but since it is *actually* mutable, then it could. So he may be suggesting it so that new developers avoid shooting themselves in the foot.

This is just a guess though, I don't know of any reason why immutables would be inherently more memory efficient.